# csv file reading having different delimiter in alternate lines in to c#

Tags: c#, csv

My .csv file look like this one row is having image name and next row is having imagepath and having n no rows like this both rows having different delimiters.

```
COL1, COL2, COL3,
"1564,1234","8018,2017,233","235,125,125"    
D:\Images\2.jpg,D:Images\4.jpg,D:\Images\3.jpg
```

in second row string in Quotes is to consider as a single image name.
My requirement is to read imagename and imagepath in single item and with that item I need create row item and binding it to datatable row.

i am getting index out of range exception at the line which made Bold, it is image tittle is giving 7 items and image path line giving 3 items .
can any one help me for this .

I created `List<list<myImage>>` and but it is not working .

```
private List<List<MyImage>> rowItemCollection;
    private string[] _columns;

    public List<List<MyImage>> ReadCsv(string filepath)
    {
        List<string> tempstring = new List<string>();

        DataTable _mydatatable = new DataTable();

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath))
        {
            rowItemCollection = new List<List<MyImage>>();
            string line;
            int lineCount = 0;
            while (!sr.EndOfStream && ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null))
            {
                var item = line.Split('"');
                if (lineCount == 0)
                {
                    _columns = item[0].Split(',');
                    int lastIndex = _columns.Count() - 1;
                    if (_columns[lastIndex].Contains('\r'))
                    {
                        _columns[lastIndex] = _columns[lastIndex].Replace("\r", "");
                    }
                    //lineCount++;
                }
                else if ((lineCount % 2) != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var Imagetittle in item)
                    {
                        if (!(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Imagetittle)))
                        {
                            tempstring.Add(Imagetittle);
                        }

                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    string[] imagePath = item[0].Split(',');
                    var _rowitem = new List<MyImage>();
                    foreach (string Imagetittle in tempstring)
                    {
                        **_rowitem.Add(new MyImage(Imagetittle, imagePath[j]));**
                        j++;
                    }
                    rowItemCollection.Add(_rowitem);
                    tempstring.Clear();

                }

                lineCount++;

            }

        }
        return rowItemCollection;
    }
```

Comment: The delimiter is a comma in every case. In the first row after the header row, the values are *quoted* because they contain commas. "it's not working" is too vague for us to help you. You'll have to show us your code and explain what the expected behavior is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Be careful when editing such raw data, it does matter if there is a CRLF or not. The OP had to clarify and show us the real format of the input text

Comment: @SirRufo Fair point.

Comment: @venky Please update the question with the real data and be **very** precise with delimiters and line breaks. Put the whole into <pre>...</pre> block and there will be no formatting at all, just the raw data

Comment: @SirRufo thanks for replying and sorry for giving not so clear.

Comment: <pre>COL1, COL2, COL3,</pre> <pre>"1564,1234","8018,2017,233","235,125,125"</pre>
<pre>D:\Images\2.jpg,D:Images\4.jpg,D:\Images\3.jpg</pre>

Comment: first row[0] is column headers , next row[1] will be image tittle row and next  row[2] is the image path row.

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks for replying .

Comment: @venky First row has really **four** colums and the other rows only **three**? And please update the question instead of writing a comment with the data

Answer (score 0):

You do not have multiple delimiters, there is only the `,`. You can read the file using a StreamReader and parse each line with your own methods.

Or you could rely on a DataDriver to do the work.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace LoadingCSVFile_44078546
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DoItAgain(@"M:\StackOverflowQuestionsAndAnswers\LoadingCSVFile_44078546\sample.txt");
        }

        private static DataTable DoItAgain(string path)
        {
            string folderPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
            string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"" + folderPath +
                "\";Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;\"";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                objConn.Open();

                OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("select * from [" + fileName + "]", objConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();

                objAdapter.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;
                objAdapter.Fill(dt);
                objConn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Do something
            }

            List<string> tmpList = new List<string>();
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)//ietrate through the record set
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)//iterate throught the columns a the record
                    {
                        /*
                         * I don't know how you want to validate the path
                         * So here's something you should replace with your own
                         */
                        if (item[i].ToString().Contains("\\"))
                        {
                            tmpList.Add(item[i].ToString());//add the path to the List<>
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            /*
             * tmpList now hold the image paths
             */

            return dt;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Updated snippet to take your updated sample data into account.